# How to change the font of a Picker?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to set the font to `title2` for the items in the Picker (e.g.`.font(Font.title2.weight(.heavy))`) so it’s of a size and type.

Unfortunately, it doesn’t read any font mentions and still displays super small font.

Here’s my code (I got rid of any of my failed experiments):

```
struct PlayView: View {
    @State private var selectedLevel = "3"
    let levels = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    @State private var selectedLife = "3"
    let lives = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
    @State private var selectedLetterMethod = "Sound"
    let letters = ["Sound", "Written"]
    @State private var showWelcomeView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack { 
        VStack() {
            HStack{
                Text("N:")
                    .font(Font.title2.weight(.heavy))
                Picker("Level (n)", selection: $selectedLevel)
                {
                    ForEach(levels, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                            .font(.title2)
                    }
                }
            }
            HStack{
                Text("Lives:")
                    .font(Font.title2.weight(.heavy))
                Picker("Lives", selection: $selectedLife) {
                    ForEach(lives, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            HStack{
                Text("Letters:")
                    .font(Font.title2.weight(.heavy))
                Picker("Letter display", selection: $selectedLetterMethod) {
                    ForEach(letters, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hey, please try to post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe try removing your other `HStacks/Picker` because they're unnecessary. Thanks!

Comment: This works for the picker styles inline and wheel but not for any others in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your `pickerStyle` to `.wheel` it will reflect all the font changes that you set.

As per your code as there is no pickerStyle the default is set to `.menu` and no font styling will be applied when its `.menu`.

Attaching a few references to support the explanation

- When PickerStyle set to `.wheel`

[image]

[image]

If you notice I have 2 picker items with different font styles and both are applied properly when `.pickerStyle` is set to `.wheel`

The first picker item as blue with a smaller font and the second item has red color with a bigger font.

- When PickerStyle is set to `.menu`

if the `pickerStyle` is set to `.menu` it shows up like below even with the same font styling

[image]

Inorder to apply any font styling you should set your Picker's `pickerStyle` value to `.wheel`

Your output would be something like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! Is there any way I can change the font of a picker selection in the “main view”? e.g. To make the “3” Belgów the same font as „N:”?

Comment: You need to set the same font to your picker text that you set for `N` along with setting the pickerStyle to `.wheel`